# JMeter Remote testing - 2 slaves

Tags: jmeter, remote-server, slave

I'm executing JMeter loadtest on my system. We have 1 client server with JMeter GUI and 2 slaves servers.

e.g.
client: 192.168.1.1
slave1: 192.168.1.2
slave2: 192.168.1.3

We are testing application where I need to login, do something and logout.
Is it possible to test such application with 2+ slaves? Because I cannot login with the same user more times on server in current session. I get license error: "User is connected from another machine".
I know, that jmeter multiplies Threads with number of slaves, but how to handle this situation?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to test your scenario with multiple different users with different login credentials in distributed architecture? Try using [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config). For Referrence: https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG

Comment: Yes, I test it with 10 - 700 different users and different credentials. But what does it mean, when more slaves multiply Threads? e.g. 100 users = 100 threads on 1 slave, but 200 threads on 2 slaves...It means that, each slave tries to login the same users...or how to explain it?

Comment: Your test plan will execute on each slave machine but can use different properties and parameters. You can use two different CSV files in different machines.

Comment: For distributed testing, the CSV file must be stored on the server host system in the correct relative directory to where the JMeter server is started.

Comment: great workaround to use 2 different csv files. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMeter uses local `CSV` files in distributed mode. So you just place different files on each slave and it works.

For distributed testing, the `CSV` file must be stored on the server host system in the correct relative directory to where the JMeter server is started.

According to the [Apache JMeter documentation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config),

> By default, the file is only opened once, and each thread will use a different line from the file. However, the order in which lines are passed to threads depends on the order in which they execute, which may vary between iterations.
>
> If you want each thread to have its own set of values, then you will need to create a set of files, one for each thread. For example test1.csv, test2.csv, …, testn.csv. Use the filename test${__threadNum}.csv and set the "Sharing mode" to "Current thread".

So just put your different credentials in different CSV.

Comment: great, it helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Either of below solutions will address your issue. I use Redis. It is super cool.

**Redis:**

http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-make-data-sharing-easy-in-distributed-mode-using-redis/

**HTTP Simple Table Server:**

https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HttpSimpleTableServer